# Why KMPlayer can't Play .m4a audio files?

Tags: kmplayer

I have downloaded some audio music files, but my KM player can't play the files? However it can easily play the rest of the music files quiet easily. Then why exception for .m4a files. Windows media player can even play this files too but KM player not. I am so annoyed. Please let me know if you have better solution of it.

Answer (score 0):

At least with an older version around 2013 (3.1.0.0), it was reommended that users change the splitter that the program uses.

> Preferences (F2) -> Splitter -> General tab and selecting MP4, MOV ->
>   Gabest splitter (or any other but not the default one).

Solution is as described here: http://forums.kmplayer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24676&highlight=m4a

Comment: Perhaps this might work? http://forums.kmplayer.com/forums/showthread.php?t=24676&highlight=m4a